# Notification API in Android Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome, android-4.4-kitkat

My web application uses the [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification).

I thought KitKat's Chrome browser was supposed to have it, or at least the old `webkitNotifications`. But both `window.Notification` and `window.webkitNotifications` are `undefined` in my tests in Chrome in Android 4.4.

Is there a way to push notifications from the browser to the user when the browser isn't visible in Android 4.4 ? Or do I still have to embed my web app in an Android application to achieve this ? Of course I'm open to other solutions than the HTML5 Notification API, as long as they're practical for my users (no flash). Or to a reliable webkit based alternative to Chrome and having a notification API.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately it seems that Chrome on Android isn't compatible with HTML5
 Notification API according to [this](http://mobilehtml5.org). BTW I tried [this demo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Demos_of_open_web_technologies#Notifications_API) 
 on chrome on my Nexus 7 with stock kit Kat on it and the demo say's my browser isn't compatible :/

Comment: Slow (very slow) clap for Google. Documented here https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-push-notifications and yet not supported (facepalm)