# Where do notifications show on Chrome on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, notifications

Consider the following.

```
if (this.Notification) {
  Notification.requestPermission(function(permission) {
    if (permission === 'granted') {
      return new Notification('hi this is a test');
    } else {
      return alert("Notifications not permitted");
    }
  });
} else {
  alert('Notifications not supported');
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zx50bqhu/).

This seems to behave as expected in Chrome on desktop. In Firefox for Android, such notifications appear in the Android notification bar.

However on Android Chrome it seems to prompt the user to allow/disallow notifications, but if the user clicks 'allow' nothing seems to happen. Does Android Chrome support this sort of notification?

**EDIT:** This is different to [this question from 18 months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361968) - then `window.Notification` wasn't defined at all. Now it is defined but doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notification API in Android Chrome browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361968/notification-api-in-android-chrome-browser)

Comment: @PawełPsztyć edited accordingly

Comment: What version of Chrome do you have?

Comment: Mine is 45.0.2454.94 on Android 4.4.2, local notifications don't work, no errors either.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle for this? And did you check your settings in Chrome (Settings > Site Settings)?

Comment: @RalphWiggum jsfiddle included.

Comment: @JosipIvic Funnily, my chrome is also 45.0.2454.94.

Comment: @RalphWiggum Settings > Site Settings > Notification s is Ask First, with permission for JSFiddle after I first confirm it. Opening in incognito will prompt every time, of course.

Comment: Could this be a Cross Origin Police as Fiddle uses iframe maybe child iframes are not allowed to call notifications.

Comment: @Martin Barker No, the same when loaded directly and on desktop works from iframe, too.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate with the following question [HTML5 Notification not working in Mobile Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512504/html5-notification-not-working-in-mobile-chrome).  
When I debug it on my Android device, I get the following error:
`Failed to construct 'Notification': Illegal constructor. Use ServiceWorkerRegistration.showNotification() instead.`

Comment: @sniels Ah... This is sad... https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/BygptYClroM Please post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a duplicate with the following question [HTML5 Notification not working in Mobile Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31512504/html5-notification-not-working-in-mobile-chrome).
When I debug it on my Android device, I get the following error:

> `Failed to construct 'Notification': Illegal constructor. Use ServiceWorkerRegistration.showNotification()`

Answer (score 0):

It should use servicework to show notification:

```
            navigator.serviceWorker.register("some-empty.js");
            Notification.requestPermission(function (result) {
                if (result === 'granted') {
                    navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function (registration) {
                        registration.showNotification('Notification with ServiceWorker');
                    });
                }
            });
```

Answer (score -2):

Android does not receive chrome notifications, it is different from desktop chrome